# Как отправить POST запрос из JS к локальному json файлу

Tags: javascript, php, json, post

Заранее извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, просто с сервером ни разу не работал. Есть необходимость на одном сайте создать форму с отправкой отзыва, а на другой странице (spa, на vue) вывести все отзывы. По моей идее я должен был с помощью fetch (axios) собрать данные и отправить их на локальный json файл, а после на другой странице с помощью get запроса получить массив с данными и на их основе сделать карточки с отзывами. Но как я слышал, js не умеет работать с локальным json файлом. Не можете подсказать как мне это реализовать? Слышал что с локальным сервером можно работать, но я работаю с vue-cli, а он тоже ругается, что мол не найден файл (json или php).

Comment: Вам нужна база данных, а не локальный JSON файл. Отправляете все отзывы на предопределённый URL с необходимыми параметрами и сохраняете в БД. После этого выполняете запрос к БД и получаете необходимые отзывы.

Comment: А не подскажете, какую базу данных выбрать? И как к ней подключиться?

Comment: Ну откуда-же я могу знать все Ваши условия, ограничения, требования и т.д.?! Что Вам хостинг предоставляет? Какая нагрузка планируется? Сколько имеется в наличии оперативной памяти и т.д. и т.п.. Соберите воедино всю информацию и от неё пляшите. На сколько помню для MySQL , SQLite и Postqres в PHP есть поддержка, но это не точно.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблема с помощью Google Firebase.

С простыми действиями (GET, POST) и не особо большой нагрузкой <1000 человек думаю хватит.